# Coordinate System [-1, 1]

Tags: opengl

I am confused on how the OpenGL coordinate system works. I know you start with object coordinates -- everything defined in its own system. Then by applying a matrix, the coordinates change to world coordinates. By applying another matrix, you have view coordinates. Then if you're working in 3D, you can apply a perspective matrix. In the end, you are left with a set of coordinates which likely are not from [-1, 1].  How does OpenGL know how to normalize them from [-1, 1]? How does it know what to clip them out? In the shader, glPosition is just given your coordinates, it doesn't know that there have been through several transformations. I know that a view to normalized coordinate matrix involves a translation and a scale, but we never explicitly make a matrix for that in OpenGL. Does OpenGL use its own hidden matrix to translate from  coordinates passed to glPostion to normalized coordinates?

Comment: There are no "hidden" matrices the only thing there is is the [perspective divide](http://www.learnopengles.com/tag/perspective-divide/).

Comment: @LJᛃ What if there is no perspective divide, for example, an orthographic projection. How does OpenGL know how to normalize the coordinates?

Comment: [Enjoy the read](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html)

Comment: @LJᛃ I think I see. So the orthographic projection matrix is more than just an identity matrix? In my Computer Graphics class, we just said the orthographic projection matrix is an identity matrix? The coordinates are normalized by the orthographic projection matrix?

Comment: I feel like you're misunderstanding something here, there is no need to normalize anything. In the end all transforms whether they're labeled *world*, *view* or *projection* are user defined and introduced, you can render without any of them. The goal here is to get things into clip space so that they appear on the screen, using matrices is just a convenient way to do so.

Comment: An identity matrix is no projection really... [this is orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection)

Comment: @LJᛃ What I'm trying to say is this: WebGL only knows how to plot points that range from [-1, 1]. Does the orthographic projection matrix result in points that range from [1,1]?

Comment: WebGL or any graphics API for that matter could easily draw things outside of that range but you want a well defined target space for your transforms, whether you orthographic projection projects vertices into this space or not is entirely up to you. Again, there is **no need to normalize anything** especially not coordinates, this would result in everything in your scene being drawn onto the screen. If you'd want that you could go ahead and build an orthographic projection matrix based on the extreme points on each axis of your vertex data and voila you just normalized all our vertices.

Comment: However in most practical applications this is not desired and/or there are better approaches. That being said, a few words of advice: stop treating your assumptions as facts, assuming things is not knowing and as long as you've not validated your assumption you should reevaluate it every time you try to reason things based upon it. The resources are all there as the links I provided you attest.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated fixed function vertex transformations are explained in https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Transformation

Shader based rendering is likely to use same or very similar math for each transformation step. The missing step between glPosition and device coordinates is perspective divide (like LJ commented quickly) where xyzw coordinates are converted to xyz coordinates. xyzw coordinates are homogeneous coordinates for 3-dimensional coordinates that use 4 components to represent a location.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates

Comment: So OpenGL divides by w for you to get the normalized coordinates? You pass in x,y,z,w to the shader?