# How Are Orthographic Coordinates Normalized?

Tags: webgl

WebGL draws coordinates that vary from -1 to 1. These coordinates become normalized by dividing by w -- the perspective divide. How does this happen with an orthographic projection because the orthographic projection matrix is the identity matrix. That is w will remain 1. How are the coordinates then normalized from [-1,1] with an orthographic projection?

Comment: This is just a rephrase of your other question, its not WebGL related(tag is for API only) and I answered exactly this in the comments on your other question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coordinate System \[-1, 1\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294457/coordinate-system-1-1)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "normalized"?

WebGL doesn't care what your matrices are it just cares what you set `gl_Position` to.

[A typical orthographic matrix](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-orthographic.html) just scales and translates `x` and `y` (and `z`) and sets `w` to 1.

The formula for how what you set `gl_Position` to gets converted to a pixel is something like

```
var x = gl_Position.x / gl.Position.w;
var y = gl_Position.y / gl.Position.w;

// convert from -1 <-> 1 to 0 to 1
var zeroToOneX = x * 0.5 + 0.5;
var zeroToOneY = y * 0.5 + 0.5;

// convert from 0 <-> 1 to viewportX <-> (viewportX + viewportWidth)
// and do something similar for Y
var pixelX = viewportX + zeroToOneX * viewportWidth;
var pixelY = viewportY + zeroToOneY * viewportHeight;
```

Where `viewportX`, `viewportY`, `viewportWidth`, and `viewportHeight` are set with `gl.viewport`

If you want the exact formula you can look [in the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) under *rasterization*.

[Maybe you might find these tutorials helpful](http://webglfundamentals.org).

Comment: I thought gl_Position must be given coordinates that range from [-1,1]?

Comment: `gl_Position` can be given any coordinates. They'll be divided by `w` and then converted to pixel values to draw triangles (or points, or lines). For values between -1 and 1 (after dividing by `w`) that will end up rendering to the canvas (or current framebuffer) using the viewport setting. But `gl_Position` does not have to be -1 to 1. Otherwise how would you draw a triangle that is partly outside of the canvas?

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. For something to appear on the screen it must range from [-1,1]. I'm confused because in my Computer Graphics class we said an orthographic projection matrix is just the identity matrix. Typically something in camera coordinates won't range from [-1,1], so I was wondering how the orthographic projection matrix normalizes them (makes the values range from -1 to 1).

Comment: An orthographic matrix is not the identity matrix. Please read the link I posted near the top of my answer. An orthographic matrix,the kind made by most math library's `orthographic(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar)` function, scales and translates coordinates so that `left<->right` goes from -1 to 1, `bottom<->top` goes from -1 to 1 and `zNear<->zFar` goes from -1 to 1.

Comment: Oh, I think I see. So the orthographic function is more than just an orthographic matrix. It is: q = MIp, where p = <x,y,z,1>, I = Identity Matrix and M = orthographic matrix, you then replace I with a matrix that translates and scales so that you get coordinates you'd like to display between [-1,1]?

Comment: Yes. I think it's easier to say `gl_Position = Projection * View * Model * Position` where Projection is usually either a perspective projection matrix (usually one that takes some negative z axis aligned frustum can converts to at [-1, 1] cube) or an orthographic projection matrix (one that takes some axis aligned 3d cube and converts to a [-1, 1] cube).

Comment: If View is the identity then you can remove it otherwise view is some matrix that moves the world in front of the *camera* or to put it another way, orients the everything so the parts we want to see are inside the axis aligned space the projection matrix will end up converting to [-1, 1]. [A view matrix is an inverse camera matrix](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html).